# Django,Error counting total number of ManyToMany related field

Tags: python, django

The model mention below,

```
class Myclass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    bad=models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,related_name='bad')
    avarage=models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,related_name='avarage')
```

I tried counting users who marked `bad` in the first object of Myclass

> `Myclass.objects.filter(id=1).bad_set.all().count()`

but got error `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'bad_set'`

Any idea what went wrong here ?

I observed that `Myclass.objects.get(id=1).bad.count()` code works if there is only one manytomany field (if I removed the `avarage` field)

Comment: Since you're using `related_name`, you don't need to use `_set` suffix. `Myclass.objects.get(id=1).bad.count()` should work.

Comment: Thanks but got error again , AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'bad'

Comment: Make sure to use `get()` instead of `filter()` to get the model instance rather than the queryset.

Comment: I tried but got same error,may be I am using two manytomanyfields in same modal

Comment: I observed that ```Myclass.objects.get(id=1).bad.count()``` code works in there is only one manytomany field

Comment: I think this SO thread will solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918968/multiple-many-to-many-relations-to-the-same-model-in-django

Comment: Thanks Harun, Do my question look low standard ? because someone downvoted it.

Comment: That thread worked for me mate, thank you have a good day

Comment: Glad to hear it worked :) I don't think it looks low quality. I think someone thinks that this problem is common and similar questions can be found, or contains some kind of typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  Harun Yilmaz suggested, added + sign at the end of related field name.

Myclass.objects.get(id=1).bad.count() worked then.